# Web scraping using R - Table of many pages

Tags: html, r, json, xml, web-scraping

I have this website which has a table of many pages. Can someone help me read all pages of that table into R?

Website: 
https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. You'll get help faster if you include a complete example of what you're trying to do, and where your code is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape the entire HTML table using the rvest package.  See the code below.  The code automatically identifies the entire table and reads in all 555 entries.

```
require(rvest)

URL <- "https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html"

failed_banks <- URL %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: How does this fetch all the data?  It doesn't seem to be doing any kind of loop?  Did you find a master table that contains all the data?  When I go to that URL, and hit F12, and search for 'table' I see 16 tables.  It seems like #13 is the main table, but again, this seems to be the only table on this page.  I can't tell how this pulls in all the data without looping through all 23 pages.  How does this work?  Can you explain the code?  Thanks.